# How do I Add http headers to Robot Franework script?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, httplib, selenium2library

I am writing a Robot Framework script and need to setup an `ADD` header and a `MODIFY` header in the robot script. 
I am using the library `httplibrary.http` and using the keywords `Setup Request Header` within the Test Case section as below.

```
Set Request Header  ${HeaderName}    ${HeaderValue}
Set Request Header  ${HeaderName1}   ${HeaderValue1}
```

I asked someone who mentioned that i need to define the variables within robot but am uncertain how to.

I have these setup in Chrome and Firefox using the Modify headers extensions as with following values.

```
Add      bypassblockingtbbmicrosite              true
Modify   X-Akamai-Edgescape                      country_code=CA
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set header then create http context and then you can make get/post call as per your requirement.

For example:

```
set request header  bypassblockingtbbmicrosite  true
set request header  X-Akamai-Edgescape  country_code=CA
Create Http Context google.com  http
get [url]
```